# Confuse with sklearn distance algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, euclidean-distance

While I want to use standard Euclidean metric in KNeighborsClassifier.

```
knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=k,metric='seuclidean' )
knn.fit(newx,y)
```

and the typeerror shown:

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py in fit(self, X, y)
    741             X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)
    742         self._y = y
--> 743         return self._fit(X)
    744 
    745 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py in _fit(self, X)
    238             self._tree = BallTree(X, self.leaf_size,
    239                                   metric=self.effective_metric_,
--> 240                                   **self.effective_metric_params_)
    241         elif self._fit_method == 'kd_tree':
    242             self._tree = KDTree(X, self.leaf_size,

sklearn\neighbors\binary_tree.pxi in sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree.BinaryTree.__init__ (sklearn\neighbors\ball_tree.c:9220)()

sklearn\neighbors\dist_metrics.pyx in sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics.DistanceMetric.get_metric (sklearn\neighbors\dist_metrics.c:4821)()

sklearn\neighbors\dist_metrics.pyx in sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics.SEuclideanDistance.__init__ (sklearn\neighbors\dist_metrics.c:6399)()

TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 positional argument (0 given)
```

I just type my own function to realize knn like:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
x = np.random.randint(0,10,(10,2))
y = np.random.randint(0,10,(10,1))
testx = np.random.randint(0,10,(1,2))
sds = StandardScaler()
sds.fit(x)
sklean_newx = sds.transform(x)
sklearn_newtestx = sds.transform(testx)
distance = np.sqrt(((testx - newx) ** 2).sum(axis=1))
for k in range(1,8):
    kn = distance.argsort()[:k]
    print(y[kn].mean(), '%'*10, k)
```

the sklearn :

```
for k in range(1,8):
    knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=k,metric='seuclidean' , metric_params={'V':x.std(axis=0)})
    knn.fit(x ,y)
    print(knn.predict(testx)[0], '%'*10, k)
```

The above two results are inconsistent, Why?

Comment: do you get that same error if you replace 'newx' and 'y' with the 'X' and 'y' from the documentation example at the bottom of this page? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `seuclidean` distance metric requires a `V` argument to satisfy the following calculation:

> `sqrt(sum((x - y)^2 / V))`

as defined in the `sklearn` [Distance Metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html) documentation.

You can pass in `V` using the `metric_params` argument in the `KNeighborsRegressor` initialization (see [KNR docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html)).

Comment: Yeah, I type this line  metric_params={'V':x.std(axis=0)}. But the result is not what I want.

Comment: Note that `sqrt` is applied to `V`, so I think you may want to pass in `var` and not `std`.  But your question was initially regarding the error, which I addressed in this answer.  Now you have changed your question to ask why two calculations are different, which is a totally different question.  Please consider keeping the text of your original question the same, and open a separate question regarding your calculation.

Comment: Thanks very much!